# View getting pushed out of screen in coordinator layout on fullscreen i.e hiding navigation button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-fullscreen, coordinator-layout

I want to implement collapsable toolbar. I have used coordinator layout to implement the same. I have a view pager in the layout and a linear layout which will be visible whole time on the screen. The view is fine when the navigation buttons are visible. But when I hide the navigation buttons, i.e. I change my theme to full screen, the linear layout at bottom gets pushed downwards outside the screen. Here is the xml coed for the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/main_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:expanded="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:scrimAnimationDuration="300"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:src="@drawable/drawable1" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/custom_view"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/scroll_behaviour">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/extra_icons_container"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/extra_icons_container"
                android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDesignV4"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDesignV4"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabBarTextStyle"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/color_v4_secondary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/extra_icons_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container3"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/drawable2"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_view_3"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/drawable3"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_two"
            style="@style/HorizontalDividerV4" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are the images :

1. with navigation buttons
   [image: Image with navigation buttons]
2. Without navigation buttons.
   [image: Image without navigation buttons]